# String to int while containing characters

Tags: java

Simple question but I am having trouble. I have an String input that is in this format `12:43`. (MM:SS). 
I am trying to convert this string in to `int` (seconds). The only part I don't know how to do is how to get `12` and `43` without getting `invalid double error`. Because it is containing that `":"` in the string, I can't do the usual `Parse.parseInt(string);` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the string according to `:`
- For each `int` in the resulting array, apply `parseInt`

Comment: I see what your saying, but I don't know Regular Expressions at all. Could you provide an example?

Comment: In this specific example, no need for special regex. You can simply do `String[] arr = myStr.split(":");`

Comment: Awesome. So `String[0]` would be minutes, then `String[1]` would be seconds?

Comment: @Binghammer and `String[0]*60 + String[1]` would be total seconds

Comment: @Binghammer By the way, Peter Lawrey's solution is probably about as efficient as possible. This is a little more java-esque though, and future readers will understand it much quicker

Comment: @Cruncher I don't think should waste time on optimization here :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Me neither, hence my tidbit about readability, I'm always interested to see the efficient solutions though :). +1 btw

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
String s = "12:43";
int secs = (s.charAt(0)-'0')*600 + (s.charAt(1) - '0') * 60 
           + (s.charAt(3)-'0')*10 + s.charAt(4)-'0';
```

or

```
int secs = s.charAt(0)*600+s.charAt(1)*60+s.charAt(3)*10+s.charAt(4)-'0'*671;
```

Comment: +1: I lolled on `-'0'*671`. This is probably the fastest way of parsing that is possible.

Comment: Not sure.  Will `'0' * 671` get optimised out into a constant?

Comment: @DavidWallace I would certainly think so

Comment: It compensates the fact that '0' != 0. While 671 == 600+60+10+1.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Yeah, after I read it 3 more times I figured it out. Thanks though!

Comment: Like that, but in the context of the question naming the variable `secs` would make sense :D

Comment: @Peter: The OP uses `MM:SS` instead of `HH:MM`.

Comment: Hey, hey, if you're going to write obfuscated code, you may as well use `mins` for this variable.  It stands for "my integer number of seconds", obviously. :)

Comment: Wow! Not immediately I understood Peter's code, but now I get it. +1 for such a non-standard-c-hacks-reminding solution!

Comment: Thank you for spotting it should be secs.